# Semi-conductors and induced charge

Tags: electrostatics, semiconductor-physics

Can a semi-conductor ( germanium or silicon) or a semi-metal ( graphite ) carry an induced charge ?

Comment: What do you mean by induced charge? An unequal number if electrons to positive charges?

Comment: Can it carry a net charge by induction like metals i think